# nth-child for every two table rows

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to make every two rows of my table grey and I would prefer to use nth-child if possible.

I've messed around with [Chris Coyier's nth-child tester](http://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/) but still can't get it.

I need the following formula:

```
1,2 - grey
3,4 - white
5,6 - grey
7,8 - white
9,10 - grey
```

and so on. I'd prefer not to put a class in the html as I'm sure that's going to be a suggestion from some. If there is a way to pull this off with nth-child, that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Please post your code, what have you tried?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Realize that you are doing groups of 4, then you can see that you can have every 4th element and every 4th element minus one being white, then every 4th element minus two, or every 4th element minus 3 being grey.

So, you'd use `4n` and `4n-1`, then `4n-2` and `4n-3`:

```
div:nth-child(4n), div:nth-child(4n-1) {
    background: red;
}
div:nth-child(4n-2), div:nth-child(4n-3) {
    background: blue;
}
```

That code isn't precise to your case, I wrote it for a [jsFiddle proof-of-concept](http://jsfiddle.net/Wte4w/).

NB disclaimer: Keep in mind that `nth-child` does not work in IE8. Typical issue, of course.

Comment: It's almost like you're *intentionally* straying away from his case by changing the elements *and* the colors :P

Comment: @BoltClock Cute... But `div`s have less markup than `table`s and `blue`/`red` are easier to see. ;)

Comment: I appreciate the solution here, but I actually need the table because it is a spreadsheet-like presentation of the content. I will keep this in mind, and if I come back to it I will be happy to accept the answer.

Comment: I thought the point of asking questions was to learn, not to get something you can copy/paste from.  If you can't translate a solution that uses a different tag than your exact mark-up, how can you hope to grow as a front end designer?

Comment: @samseabom if you want your code ready for production, you can always hire Eric...

Comment: This fiddle is a clean solution based on Eric's original example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Wte4w/338/

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I'm using to right-align the first column of each table.

```
table td:nth-child(2n-1) {
    align: right;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Eric's answer is exactly right - but if you want to easily extend this to groups of 3, 4, 5, etc, and you're using Sass, here's the code (if you want more groups, just increase `$largestGroupSize`):

```
.table-with-grouped-rows {

    // generate styles for .groups-of-2, .groups-of-3, etc.
    $largestGroupSize: 6;
    @for $groupNumPerColor from 2 through $largestGroupSize{

        $totalGroupNum: $groupNumPerColor * 2;

        &.groups-of-#{$groupNumPerColor} {

            $start: $totalGroupNum - 1;
            $end: $groupNumPerColor;
            @for $primaryBgIndex from $start through $end {
                $nthString: #{$totalGroupNum}n - #{$primaryBgIndex};

                > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(#{$nthString}) > td {
                    background-color: $white;
                }
            }

            $start: $groupNumPerColor - 1;
            $end: 0;
            @for $alternateBgIndex from $start through $end {
                $nthString: #{$totalGroupNum}n - #{$alternateBgIndex};
                > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(#{$nthString}) > td {
                    background-color: $light-gray;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then in your markup, on the `<table>` element, you'd simply add the classes `table-with-grouped-rows` and `groups-of-{n}`. For example, if you want a table with groups of 3, you'd write:

```
<table class="table-with-grouped-rows groups-of-3">
```

Boom.