# HTML/CSS3 table rows: first 2 rows white, next 2 rows gray, then next 2 white again, and so on?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [nth-child for every two table rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375293/nth-child-for-every-two-table-rows)

I'm trying to work my way into the CSS3 `nth-child` selector, but it seems I can't get it working at the moment.

What I would like to do is make the first 2 rows in a table white, then next 2 rows gray, then next 2 white again and so on. How would I do this using only CSS?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a little bit of fiddling (literally) I finally hit on an answer:

CSS:

```
tr:nth-child(4n+0), tr:nth-child(4n-1) {
    background-color: grey;
}​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/3e4Fz/

This selects every 4th row starting at 0 and at -1, you can target the rows in between by using `nth-child(4n-2)` and `nth-child(4n-3)`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/nGSfz/

Comment: Thank you! In fact it isn't difficult at all, it seems. This makes clear a lot to me!