# nth-child to alternate by 2 rows

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to use CSS3's `nth-child` selector to alternate between background color two rows thick, rather than the usual one row when using `nth-child(odd)`.

[The "Result" section of this jsFiddle illustrates what I want.](http://jsfiddle.net/QXybw/)

So we would have a table:

```
ROW 1: Blue
ROW 2: Blue
ROW 3: Red
ROW 4: Red
ROW 5: Blue
ROW 6: Blue
```

Comment: Also, your Fiddle doesn't actually illustrate what you've put in the question; the demo has rows 1-2 as red, while your question specifies 1-2 as blue. Not a big deal, but it makes the answers below confusing because they're answering the Fiddle rather than your written specs.

Comment: For an easily extendable Sass solution, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51090400/422845)

Answer (score 30):

You can use this:

```
tr {
    background: blue;
}

tr:nth-child(4n+1), tr:nth-child(4n+2) {
    background: red;
}
```

`n` will count from 0 and up.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QXybw/1/)**

Comment: awesome man.. had been thinking quiet a lot to figure this out.. ease (Y)

Comment: For an easily extendable Sass version, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51090400/422845)