# How to assign same background color to two rows in Bootstrap 3 stripe table?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this table and want to have the table rows inside the loop with the same colors. By default bootstrap alternates the background colors every row. But I would like to have two rows grouped together. Is there a was to accomplish this? Regards Thorsten

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tbody>
    <cfloop query="items">
      <tr>
       <td>asdfasdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>asdfasfd</td>
      </tr>
    </cfloop>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nth-child to alternate by 2 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994062/nth-child-to-alternate-by-2-rows)

Answer (score 2):

Just create your own table class and add the CSS suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22994148/3334049).

```
.my-table-class tr {
    /* Example color */
    background: blue;
}

.my-table-class tr:nth-child(4n+1), .my-table-class tr:nth-child(4n+2) {
    /* Example color */
    background: red;
}
```