# nth-child: how to pick elements in groups of two

Tags: css, css-selectors

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
 <div class="fc-slats">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="fc-widget-content fc-major">16</td>
        <td class="fc-widget-content fc-minor">16</td>
        <td class="fc-widget-content fc-major">17</td>
        <td class="fc-widget-content fc-major">17</td>
        <td class="fc-widget-content fc-major">18</td>
        <td class="fc-widget-content fc-minor">18</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
```

And I want the first and second cells to have one color, the third and fourth cells to have another color, the fifth and sixth cells to have the the first color... In other words, it's the old odd-even alternating color scheme, except with two cells in each group.

I am trying to do this with CSS's `nth-child` selector:

```
fc-slats td:nth-child(int(n/2)) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

But I don't know how exactly to write the formula for the "nth-child" selector. I suppose CSS doesn't support there math functions like `int`, or conditionals like `if... then`, so in that case, how would I achieve this?

EDIT: I just added 6 cells in this table for the sake of brevity, but assume that the table is going to have an arbitrary length; in other words, I'm looking for an "universal" solution.

Comment: you may get the list of td (with jquery for example) and set each element into odd or even class accordingly.

Comment: @Shiping: I was hoping for a non-JS solution. If I have to write Javascript... I guess I'll have to write it, but I was trying to explore other alternatives.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can select every fourth `td` along with its immediately preceding sibling with `nth-child(4n)` and `nth-child(4n - 1)`:

```css
td {
  background: blue;
}

td:nth-child(4n), td:nth-child(4n - 1) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
 <div class="fc-slats">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="fc-widget-content fc-major">16</td>
        <td class="fc-widget-content fc-minor">16</td>
        <td class="fc-widget-content fc-major">17</td>
        <td class="fc-widget-content fc-major">17</td>
        <td class="fc-widget-content fc-major">18</td>
        <td class="fc-widget-content fc-minor">18</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But what would happen if I had a longer list of cells? I just added 6 for the example, but imagine if it was a table of arbitrary length.

Comment: The pattern will repeat. Which means if we added one more cell above, it would be colored red. The `n` in `4n` means every fourth one, and similarly for `4n - 1`. Do you need a different effect?

Answer (score 1):

```
td {
    background: blue;
}

td:nth-child(4n+1), td:nth-child(4n+2) {
    background: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2nLtgd9z/

It has already been answered on StackOverflow, do your research first: [nth-child to alternate by 2 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994062/nth-child-to-alternate-by-2-rows)

Comment: You can flag questions as duplicate instead of answering them again.

Comment: @Purag I don't have the reputation to do so.