# How to set 2 different classes by if else condtion in foreach loop with predefined order?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

Suppose I have 10 records, and 2 different classes namely c1, c2

```
 <div class="c2">..content..</div>
<div class="c2">..content..</div>
<div class="c1">..content..</div>
<div class="c1">..content..</div>
<div class="c2">..content..</div>
<div class="c2">..content..</div>
<div class="c1">..content..</div>
<div class="c1">..content..</div>
<div class="c2">..content..</div>
<div class="c2">..content..</div>
```

i want the if else condition where class order needs to maintained like c2,c2,c1,c1,c2,c2,c1,c1,c2,c2.....so on

```
foreach(x as y){ 
if() {
   <div class="<?php echo $class1;?>">..content..</div>
} else { 
 <div class="<?php echo $class2;?>">..content..</div>
}
```

**class order should be c2,c2,c1,c1,c2,c2,c1,c1,c2,c2.....so on**

Check the page url http://themesflat.com/html/nah/portfolio-creative.html

Comment: does your content order matter

Comment: If you just want to style them differently, you could probably do this in CSS alone. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43483884/nth-child-how-to-pick-elements-in-groups-of-two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
    $counter = 1;

    for($i=0;$i<=10; $i++){

        if($counter==1 or $counter==2) {
           echo '<div class="c1">..content..</div>';
        } else { 
           echo '<div class="c2">..content..</div>';
        }


        if($counter==4){
          $counter=0;
        }

        $counter++;
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Simple and Exact Answer. Thanks @abrar

Answer (score 3):

You can use a bitwise operator (&) here, and with 2 and this will toggle the class...

```
$i = 0;
foreach($x as $y){
    if($i & 2) {
        $class = "1";
    } else {
        $class = "2";
    }
    echo "<div class=$class>..content..</div>";
    $i++;
}
```

I've extracted the echo out as this keeps it consistent, just have a variable for the class you want to have and put that in the if instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a separate counter

```
$current = 'c2';
$count   = 1;

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo '<div class="'. $current . '">..content..</div>';

    if ($count == 2) {
        $current = $current == 'c1' ? 'c2' : 'c1';
        $count = 0;
    }
    $count++;
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/7ftjg

This will of course work just as well in a `foreach`-loop.

**Note:** If it's only about styling the divs differently, you could do this in CSS alone. Here's a similar question and answer: [nth-child: how to pick elements in groups of two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43483884/nth-child-how-to-pick-elements-in-groups-of-two)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can resolve the problem via css pseudo class :nth-of-type but if you prefered PHP you can try the following example.

```
<?php
$class_types = ['c2', 'c1'];

$records = array_fill(0, 10, '..content..'); // replace with your records
$records_length = count($records);

$html_output = '';

foreach ($records as $index => $item) {
    $type = floor($index / $records_length * $records_length / 2) % 2;
    $class = $class_types[$type];
    $html_output .= sprintf('<div class="%s">%s</div>', $class, $item);
}

echo $html_output;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about we chunk the main array into an array or arrays of two
like

```
<?php 

$chunked_array = array_chunk( $your_array , 2 );

// This will give us an array of 2 elements array
// now we will loop
for( $i = 1 ; $i < count( $chunked_array ); $++ ){

  $contents = $chunked_array[$i];
  foreach( $contents as $content ){

    if ( $i%2 == 0 ){
      //<div class="<?php echo $class1;?>">..content..</div>
    }else{
      //<div class="<?php echo $class2;?>">..content..</div>
    }

  }

}
```

using this way we have one loop and it will always be in a group of two even when your data grow or shrink