# How to alternate table row colors when your row has inner rows

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I'm trying to add alternate table row colors in my website for NBA live scores but my table is a little weird since each table row contains an inner table row for the given quarter of the game. I'd like for each team1, scores, quarter, and team2 combination to have the same background color. Here's what it currently looks like and my code:

[image]

HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="left" style="width:40%; ">Home</th>
            <th style="width:10%;" colspan="2">Scores</th>
            <th class ="right" style="width:40%;">Away</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="tableData">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
else {
    data += `<tr>
                 <td class="left" rowspan="2"> ${item.team1} <img src=${item.team1Img}></td>
                 <td> ${item.score1} </td>
                 <td> ${item.score2} </td>
                 <td class="right" rowspan="2"> <img src=${item.team2Img}>  ${item.team2}</td>
             </tr>

             <tr>
                 <td class="period" colspan="2">Final</td>
             </tr>`;
}
```

CSS:

```
tr:nth-child(3n+0) {
    background-color: #1b1b1b;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Maybe all I need is a different nth child formula, not sure how it works and couldn't find more advanced resources online.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer after rewording my question a few times: tr:nth-child(4n+1), tr:nth-child(4n+2)

This would select every 2 table rows.

Answer found here: [nth-child to alternate by 2 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994062/nth-child-to-alternate-by-2-rows)